# notice Tried for 122 seconds to get a connection to scrubbed:80. Giving up

Tags: python, tor

Getting belowerror while sending multiple http requests through tor circuit. Is the issue because I am opening just one tor circuit to send all http requests? Does tor circuit limit number of requests?

```
Sep 18 17:59:13.000 [notice] New control connection opened.
Sep 18 17:59:28.000 [warn] Destination '[scrubbed]' seems to be an invalid hostname. Failing.
Sep 18 18:00:15.000 [notice] We tried for 15 seconds to connect to '[scrubbed]' using exit $5E56738E7F97AA81DEEF59AF28494293DFBFCCDF~Backplane at 172.98.193.43. Retrying on a new circuit.
Sep 18 18:00:31.000 [notice] We tried for 15 seconds to connect to '[scrubbed]' using exit $B0279A521375F3CB2AE210BDBFC645FDD2E1973A~chulak at 176.126.252.11. Retrying on a new circuit.
Sep 18 18:01:39.000 [notice] We tried for 65 seconds to connect to '[scrubbed]' using exit $379FB450010D17078B3766C2273303C358C3A442~aurora at 176.126.252.12. Retrying on a new circuit.
Sep 18 18:01:39.000 [notice] Tried for 122 seconds to get a connection to [scrubbed]:80. Giving up.
Sep 18 18:01:40.000 [warn] Destination '[scrubbed]' seems to be an invalid hostname. Failing.
Sep 18 18:02:40.000 [notice] Tor has not observed any network activity for the past 127 seconds. Disabling circuit build timeout recording.
Sep 18 18:03:40.000 [notice] Tried for 120 seconds to get a connection to [scrubbed]:80. Giving up. (waiting for circuit)
Sep 18 18:03:54.000 [notice] Tor now sees network activity. Restoring circuit build timeout recording. Network was down for 200 seconds during 37 circuit attempts.
Sep 18 18:04:10.000 [warn] Destination '[scrubbed]' seems to be an invalid hostname. Failing.
Sep 18 18:04:49.000 [notice] We tried for 15 seconds to connect to '[scrubbed]' using exit $F3B72E1EE437FE92EACF7E43D941D250290F2B71~bravopanchino at 192.195.80.10. Retrying on a new circuit.
Sep 18 18:05:04.000 [notice] We tried for 15 seconds to connect to '[scrubbed]' using exit $162F7E752504C49A656FF1E9669E0B9572CE4870~Necto5 at 93.115.95.206. Retrying on a new circuit.
Sep 18 18:05:19.000 [notice] We tried for 15 seconds to connect to '[scrubbed]' using exit $30C19B81981F450C402306E2E7CFB6C3F79CB6B2~Libero at 64.113.32.29. Retrying on a new circuit.
Sep 18 18:05:34.000 [notice] We tried for 15 seconds to connect to '[scrubbed]' using exit $DAB96CEA61CC039A803217035293FAB32645FDDA~kree at 85.248.227.165. Retrying on a new circuit.
Sep 18 18:05:49.000 [notice] We tried for 15 seconds to connect to '[scrubbed]' using exit $636E4E7D41530E064D61F57586F2F75F83271482~xerileez177 at 89.144.12.15. Retrying on a new circuit.
Sep 18 18:06:04.000 [notice] We tried for 15 seconds to connect to '[scrubbed]' using exit $DA0FE8B5DD9717F52376F55885BC72E619ACD97D~heine at 51.15.53.83. Retrying on a new circuit.
Sep 18 18:06:19.000 [notice] We tried for 15 seconds to connect to '[scrubbed]' using exit $7A3DD280EA4CD4DD16EF8C67B93D9BDE184D1A81~Quintex39 at 199.249.223.48. Retrying on a new circuit.
Sep 18 18:06:19.000 [notice] Tried for 125 seconds to get a connection to [scrubbed]:80. Giving up.
Sep 18 18:07:05.000 [notice] We tried for 15 seconds to connect to '[scrubbed]' using exit $21954C79058F62F8A3C1EF5E5FC16657F924711C~OxylEta at 89.45.226.28. Retrying on a new circuit.
Sep 18 18:07:20.000 [notice] We tried for 15 seconds to connect to '[scrubbed]' using exit $AD9B580836C9942317E9B7664EC7B39075DEBB5B~PiratenNDS3 at 46.165.223.217. Retrying on a new circuit.
Sep 18 18:07:35.000 [notice] We tried for 15 seconds to connect to '[scrubbed]' using exit $BC630CBBB518BE7E9F4E09712AB0269E9DC7D626~IPredator at 197.231.221.211. Retrying on a new circuit.
Sep 18 18:07:50.000 [notice] We tried for 15 seconds to connect to '[scrubbed]' using exit $5DC945CE8FB2A37E6E2795ECD2709BB21F8714B0~Unnamed at 207.244.70.35. Retrying on a new circuit.
Sep 18 18:08:05.000 [notice] We tried for 15 seconds to connect to '[scrubbed]' using exit $B84F248233FEA90CAD439F292556A3139F6E1B82~tollana at 85.248.227.164. Retrying on a new circuit.
Sep 18 18:08:20.000 [notice] We tried for 15 seconds to connect to '[scrubbed]' using exit $71AB4726D830FAE776D74AEF790CF04D8E0151B4~niftycottontail at 51.15.34.210. Retrying on a new circuit.
Sep 18 18:08:35.000 [notice] We tried for 15 seconds to connect to '[scrubbed]' using exit $EC116BCB80565A408CE67F8EC3FE3B0B02C3A065~orion at 94.242.246.24. Retrying on a new circuit.
Sep 18 18:08:35.000 [notice] Tried for 125 seconds to get a connection to [scrubbed]:80. Giving up.
Sep 18 18:09:12.000 [notice] We tried for 15 seconds to connect to '[scrubbed]' using exit $9C1E7D92115D431385B8CAEA6A7C15FB89CE236B~QuintexAirVPN21 at 199.249.224.40. Retrying on a new circuit.
Sep 18 18:09:27.000 [notice] We tried for 15 seconds to connect to '[scrubbed]' using exit $CDA2EA326E2272C57ACB26773D7252C211795B78~niftygerbil at 51.15.70.226. Retrying on a new circuit.
Sep 18 18:09:42.000 [notice] We tried for 15 seconds to connect to '[scrubbed]' using exit $734EDDC2C04B1C0184178167ABD23AE85413212F~torlesnet1 at 199.87.154.255. Retrying on a new circuit.
Sep 18 18:09:57.000 [notice] We tried for 15 seconds to connect to '[scrubbed]' using exit $DAB96CEA61CC039A803217035293FAB32645FDDA~kree at 85.248.227.165. Retrying on a new circuit.
Sep 18 18:10:12.000 [notice] We tried for 15 seconds to connect to '[scrubbed]' using exit $4198BD138E5E11B15B05C826B427148CED7D99FE~ParEpistemenTaksis at 163.172.101.137. Retrying on a new circuit.
Sep 18 18:10:27.000 [notice] We tried for 15 seconds to connect to '[scrubbed]' using exit $734EDDC2C04B1C0184178167ABD23AE85413212F~torlesnet1 at 199.87.154.255. Retrying on a new circuit.
Sep 18 18:10:42.000 [notice] We tried for 15 seconds to connect to '[scrubbed]' using exit $09FA8B4F665AD65D2C2A49870F1AA3BA8811E449~StanMarsh at 216.218.222.12. Retrying on a new circuit.
Sep 18 18:10:42.000 [notice] Tried for 125 seconds to get a connection to [scrubbed]:80. Giving up.
Sep 18 18:11:42.000 [notice] We tried for 15 seconds to connect to '[scrubbed]' using exit $FDAED15C98CFE7A416E5676F614254F78406105C~dorrisdeebrown at 192.36.27.4. Retrying on a new circuit.
Sep 18 18:11:57.000 [notice] We tried for 15 seconds to connect to '[scrubbed]' using exit $68E67F1ABC55915E796E7011C8867909E74E2890~warsaw at 145.239.29.201. Retrying on a new circuit.
Sep 18 18:12:12.000 [notice] We tried for 15 seconds to connect to '[scrubbed]' using exit $12D17D9F9E30FA901DE68806950A0EA278716CED~AccessNow011 at 176.10.99.205. Retrying on a new circuit.
Sep 18 18:12:27.000 [notice] We tried for 15 seconds to connect to '[scrubbed]' using exit $2C539063E38B8DA96DBE742682AAD23954CDB807~kljlkjjlklkjlk at 149.202.51.88. Retrying on a new circuit.
Sep 18 18:12:42.000 [notice] We tried for 15 seconds to connect to '[scrubbed]' using exit $30C19B81981F450C402306E2E7CFB6C3F79CB6B2~Libero at 64.113.32.29. Retrying on a new circuit.
Sep 18 18:12:57.000 [notice] We tried for 15 seconds to connect to '[scrubbed]' using exit $311A4533F7A2415F42346A6C8FA77E6FD279594C~DigiGesTor3e2 at 178.209.42.84. Retrying on a new circuit.
Sep 18 18:13:12.000 [notice] We tried for 15 seconds to connect to '[scrubbed]' using exit $9AA3FF35E7A549D2337E962333D366E102FE4D50~DigiGesTor3e1 at 178.209.42.84. Retrying on a new circuit.
Sep 18 18:13:12.000 [notice] Tried for 125 seconds to get a connection to [scrubbed]:80. Giving up.
Sep 18 18:14:06.000 [notice] We tried for 15 seconds to connect to '[scrubbed]' using exit $B771AA877687F88E6F1CA5354756DF6C8A7B6B24~niftypika at 163.172.140.123. Retrying on a new circuit.
Sep 18 18:14:21.000 [notice] We tried for 15 seconds to connect to '[scrubbed]' using exit $335746A6DEB684FABDF3FC5835C3898F05C5A5A8~KyleBroflovski at 216.218.222.11. Retrying on a new circuit.
Sep 18 18:14:36.000 [notice] We tried for 15 seconds to connect to '[scrubbed]' using exit $2C9C6E818CDEC876CF34627A034E7187084D8D6B~BabylonNetwork07 at 51.15.60.255. Retrying on a new circuit.
Sep 18 18:14:51.000 [notice] We tried for 15 seconds to connect to '[scrubbed]' using exit $F6A358DD367B3282D6EF5824C9D45E1A19C7E815~prawksi at 192.160.102.168. Retrying on a new circuit.
Sep 18 18:15:08.000 [notice] We tried for 15 seconds to connect to '[scrubbed]' using exit $1FEC860E59949E60D112FA26649CF0E32693FB4F~watchme at 163.172.212.115. Retrying on a new circuit.
Sep 18 18:15:23.000 [notice] We tried for 15 seconds to connect to '[scrubbed]' using exit $74A19D86DDF63F1133B414B81F36E1F44640811F~Unnamed at 62.210.105.116. Retrying on a new circuit.
Sep 18 18:15:38.000 [notice] We tried for 15 seconds to connect to '[scrubbed]' using exit $1388E7C77373197D4DB4CF406C0513D2D5847613~Andromeda1 at 195.123.212.118. Retrying on a new circuit.
Sep 18 18:15:38.000 [notice] Tried for 127 seconds to get a connection to [scrubbed]:80. Giving up.
Sep 18 18:16:30.000 [notice] We tried for 15 seconds to connect to '[scrubbed]' using exit $5CECC5C30ACC4B3DE462792323967087CC53D947~PrivacyRepublic0001 at 178.32.181.96. Retrying on a new circuit.
Sep 18 18:16:46.000 [notice] We tried for 15 seconds to connect to '[scrubbed]' using exit $DAA3D3F6FDA962885072537E3F315086B003A6E3~DC225TorExitNode at 46.101.139.248. Retrying on a new circuit.
Sep 18 18:17:04.000 [notice] We tried for 15 seconds to connect to '[scrubbed]' using exit $B84F248233FEA90CAD439F292556A3139F6E1B82~tollana at 85.248.227.164. Retrying on a new circuit.
Sep 18 18:17:20.000 [notice] We tried for 15 seconds to connect to '[scrubbed]' using exit $AFF2FC5C6F793B6E147EB93C1897D6DDA49E54FD~Wix at 5.196.66.162. Retrying on a new circuit.
Sep 18 18:17:37.000 [notice] We tried for 15 seconds to connect to '[scrubbed]' using exit $5DC945CE8FB2A37E6E2795ECD2709BB21F8714B0~Unnamed at 207.244.70.35. Retrying on a new circuit.
Sep 18 18:17:54.000 [notice] We tried for 15 seconds to connect to '[scrubbed]' using exit $379FB450010D17078B3766C2273303C358C3A442~aurora at 176.126.252.12. Retrying on a new circuit.
Sep 18 18:17:54.000 [notice] Tried for 122 seconds to get a connection to [scrubbed]:80. Giving up.
```

Below is the code. I am sending DNS query first and then http request to that IP, over a list of websites. What can be the issue here ? I have 1000 websites in the list.

```
r = dns.resolver.Resolver()
r.nameservers = ['127.0.0.1']
r.port = 9053

with open("testWeb.txt") as f:
    content = f.readlines()
urls = [x.strip() for x in content]


with Controller.from_port(port = 9051) as controller:
    controller.authenticate(password='')
    socks.setdefaultproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5, "127.0.0.1", 9050)
    temp = socket.socket
    socket.socket = socks.socksocket

    for url in urls:
        try:
            answer_tor = r.query(url)
        except Exception as e:
            print "Exception in website : " + url + " " + e.message

        try:
            req = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: "+url+"\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\nCache-Control: max-age=0\r\nUpgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1\r\nUser-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/58.0.3029.110 Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36\r\nAccept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8\r\nAccept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8\r\n\r\n"
            controller.authenticate(password='')                
            # http request to tor circuit IP
            Url = (str(answer_tor[0]), 80)
            d = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM, proto=socket.IPPROTO_TCP)
            d.connect(Url)
            d.send(req)
            tor_response = str(d.recv(12288))
            d.close()
        except Exception as e:
            ExceptionHappenedWhileExperiment.append("Exception in website : " + url + " " + e.message)
            print "Exception in website : " + url + " " + e.message
```